# Influenza infections and drug design

Tags: pharmacology, receptor, infectious-diseases

Why is the *neuraminidase* used as a target for drugs against influenza virus instead of *haemagglutinin*? Is there some basic reason that this will make a more effective drug?

Comment: Can you add any research you've already done on this?

Answer (score 3):

It's not that people didn't want to use hemagglutinin as a target for antivirals, it's that they haven't been able to get the antivirals through the approval process yet. There are a number of experimental inhibitors (see for example [Progress of small molecular inhibitors in the development of anti-influenza virus agents](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5381247/)) but the approval and licensing process is slow and difficult.